# How to "translate" form serialization named properties to make model binding work?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, model-binding

My View Model

```
public class TaskFormViewModel 
    {
        public Task Task { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Problem> Problems { get; set; }
    }
```

With that, in my View my inputs have the current markup

```
<input class="form-control" asp-for="Task.Prop1">
```

And so on...

So when I send my form using AJAX (I fill the data property with `$(form).serialize()`)
 I get something like that:

```
 $.ajax({
     //other configs
     data: $form.serialize() //$form is my variable name
});
```

| Property | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Task.Prop1 | 'aaaaaa' |
| Task.Prop2 | 'bbbbb' |

But look at my action, if I use taskDto as name of the parameter, it can't bind the properties to the model. And I don't want to rename it to just task, because I already have a variable with name `task` that is result of mapping `TaskDto` to `Task`. This can sound silly but all other action in my application works well with this convention that I've been using.

```
// Not works
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Insert([FromForm] TaskDto taskDto)
```

```
// Works
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Insert([FromForm] TaskDto task)
```

How can I achive the right model binding without renaming the `taskDto` parameter name to `task`?

I don't know if is a  good idea to put a Dto into the View Model (since in other parts I didn't have the need to do that)
Or imagine changing the name of the serialized form to match `TaskDto`:

| Property | Value |
| --- | --- |
| TaskDto.Prop1 | 'aaaaaa' |
| TaskDto.Prop2 | 'bbbbb' |

Answer (score 0):

Serializing is the wrong way to go.

If you want the nested attributes you want javascript FormData.

The below example will send the form via ajax with the proper naming and structure.

```
var formdata = new FormData($(form)[0]);

$.ajax({
    data: formdata,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function(data){
        //DO SOMETHING WITH SUCCESS        
    }
})
```

Comment: Still receiving bad request 400 error for the fields required's.
It works using `serialize()` or `FormData` but with parameter name in my action called `task`. If I put `taskDto` the model binding fail

Comment: The example I gave was not the full ajax.... I dont know what url your need to send to... nor do i know if it should be post or get... or if headers should be included....
What does the payload show in the network tab on the browser developer console?

Comment: I'm calling the url `/api/tasks`, to call the Action showed in the question `Insert` (POST method)

Comment: so then you would need to add `type: 'post'` and `url: '/api/tasks'` in the ajax parameters

Comment: My current `$.ajax` call is `$.ajax({
                            url: '/api/tasks',
                            processData: false,
                            contentType: false,
                            method: 'POST',
                            data: new FormData($form.get(0))
                        })`

I use .done() after to manage the success action

Comment: new FormData($(form)[0]) is the correct syntax

Comment: They are the same thing. Nothing changes.

Comment: whats the output of console.log($form.serialize()) ?

Comment: I suspect your field names aren't rendering correctly. But checking $(form).serialize() will confirm if the form is actually capable of collapsing data to send over ajax